# My VBA says there is an error on my sub name

Tags: vba, excel

I have combined two VBA's into one but I'm getting an error on the first line where I declare OpenLatestFile as a public sub

I'm trying to grab the latest file and paste that file into my second sheet called LastQuerySave

```
'Force the explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit

Public Sub OpenLatestFile()

'Declare the variables
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteStart As Range

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteStart = [LastQuerySave!A1]
Sheets("LastQuerySave").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

'Specify the path to the folder
MyPath = "M:\Users\Dan\Access\DiscontinueQuery\DiscontinueQuerySave\"

'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

'Get the first Excel file from the folder
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

'If no files were found, exit the sub
If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

    'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
    
    'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
    'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If
    
    'Get the next Excel file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir
    
Loop

'Open the latest file
 set wb2 =  Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
    With Sheet.UsedRange
        .Copy PasteStart
        Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
    End With
Next Sheet

wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: im thinking somehow add a call statement to replace the file to open part. I cant seem to do it without errors

Comment: In the 2nd procedure replace `Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile` with `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile`. Then add the `For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets` loop from first procedure.

Comment: I have pasted what you suggested with an error. please let me know whats wrong

Comment: You need `Set wb2 = ` in front of `Workbooks.Open MyPath ...`

Comment: I Updated with that. Still doesnt work. Says MyPath on that line is wrong

Comment: When you use `Set` you need to encapsulate object arguments with parentheses. `Set wb2 =  Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile)`

Comment: 3 Errors i am getting
(Sub OpenOldestFile()) and 
(Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook) and (Set PasteStart = [LastQuerrySave!A1])

Comment: The document runs, but it also tells me there are those 3 errors. Thank you Scott you were great help!